# Tripple-void delete operator syntax

Tags: c++

I have come across the following line of code which exists as a free variable inside a Cpp file.

`void* DeleteFunctionPointer = (void*)(void(*)(void*))(::operator delete[]);`

Can someone explain to me the syntax and what is the variable's purpose?

Comment: Why don't you ask the person who wrote it?

Comment: Have them add a documenting comment to the code while you're at it

Comment: This comes from a third party library and I don't have access to the creators of it, this is why I asked here.

Comment: There are no contact details included with it whatsoever? Who gave it to you, then? While we can tell you what the code means in abstract terms, only the author can tell why they wrote it, and how it fits into the architecture of the remainder of the code. I suggest you look a little more closely for their contact information/project website. Stack Overflow is not the best place for asking about individual lines of code from other people's projects. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I was more interested in understanding the syntax as it looked really odd to me, this is why I asked here. I will do more research on it.

Comment: Alright, cool..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is 2 casts in:

`(void*)(void(*)(void*))(::operator delete[]);`

`(void*)` casts final result to `void*`.

`(void(*)(void*))` cast to pointer function taking `void*` and returning `void`.

Comment: Is casting a function pointer to an object pointer valid? I forget.

Comment: @LightnessRacesBY-SA3.0 It is conditionally supported with implementation-defined behavior except for the round-trip conversion (if supported at all): https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.reinterpret.cast#8

Comment: @walnut Aight. Might be worth noting that it's not "great" code then. Something like "what this actually _means_ or _does_ is a bit wooly [ref] so it may not be the best example of C++ code. I recommend discussing with the author what the intended function is and whether it can be relied upon."